# Trigger mechanism in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

Lets say I'm creating a game like Flappy bird, I wanted to trigger when ever the player passes between two pipes so that i can count how many pipes dose the player crossed.

[image: This is the Trigger i wanted]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions, don't just add any tags with "unit" or "unity" in them.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Should i post the question on gamedev again ?? @LearnCocos2D

Comment: Yes, and with more information unless you want a general answer like "create collision boxes between pillars".

Answer (score 3):

Create a gameobject with a `BoxCollider` component, but no renderer.

Scale the BoxCollider such that it encompasses your trigger area.

Then set the collider as a trigger and attach a script to it that contains some desired functionality in the `OnTriggerEntered` function.

**Note**: your player gameobject should have a rigid body and collider attached to it, or no collisions will be recorded.

If you wish for this trigger to appear with every obstacle, add it to your obstacle prefab.