# Unity Check if an object collided at a position

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

My problem is that I can't figure out how to check if an object eg. player has collided at a certain position with a for eg. wall.

Now what I mean is if the player has an x scale of lets say of 5, how would I check if the player collided with the wall at the end of the player. If I'm correct I would have to check if it collided at it's position of 2,5.

Comment: Ask this in Game Development SE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger mechanism in Unity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450414/trigger-mechanism-in-unity)

Comment: You could also use the positions of the objects along with their collider bounds to deduce the approximate location of contact, but if the answer below works for you, it's definitely the simpler approach. All the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add (for example) a `Box Collider` component to each of your `GameObjects`

Then, if you want to visually show a detection, you can Debug when the collision took place:

For example, in the `Player` script:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) 
{
    Debug.Log("Collision!");
}
```

If you wanted to check for a precise point of a collision, you could use the same technique but make the `Box Collider` smaller.

Comment: This is very, "limited",  because I need to check on 4 sides and on each side it must do a different thing. Maybe a solution would be to add an empty object at each side and add a collider for it and a script for each one ?

Comment: You could add an empty GameObject on each one - but I wouldn't create a script for each one - instead I would tag these Gameobjects, and create a check for each one - `if (gameobject.tag == "1"){do something} if (gameobject.tag == "2"){do something}`

Comment: Yea and I should put this script on the wall so it actually does this when I hit the wall. Thanks.

Comment: hi Nikola - that's exactly what you do.  If for some reason you want to "know" about more than one area, use a collider on each of those areas.

Comment: That's what I planned to do :D